# Problem by a reference variable of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, lvalue

The following small example shows my problem:

```
template<class T> struct X
{
    static void xxx(T& x) { }
    static void xxx(T&& x) { }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 9;
    X<int>::xxx(x); // OK.
    X<int&>::xxx(x); // ERROR!
    return 0;
}
```

Error message (GCC):

> error: ‘static void X::xxx(T&&) [with T = int&]’ cannot be overloaded
>   error: with ‘static void X::xxx(T&) [with T = int&]’

Why? `T = int&` ---> Is `T&` replaced by `int&&` in `static void xxx(T& x)`?

If the answer to the question is yes, then:

- `T&` is not a lvalue-reference and it becomes a rvalue-reference!
- And the following code should work:

But it didn't:

```
template<class T> struct X
{
    static void xxx(T& x) { }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    X<int&>::xxx(2); // ERROR!
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message (GCC):

> error: no matching function for call to ‘X::xxx(int)’
>   note: candidates are: static void X::xxx(T&) [with T = int&]

Then `T&` with `T = int&` is not equal to `T&&` and is not a rvalue-reference. but if it is not, why the first example not working? (it's a recursive problem!)

---

But the similar problem didn't occur for pointer types:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct X
{
    static void xxx(T* x) { std::cout << **x << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 10;
    int* xx = &x;
    X<int*>::xxx(&xx); // OK. call X<int*>::xxx(int**)
    return 0;
}
```

Why references are different in this behavior?

Comment: My head hurts.  So many ampersands.

Comment: &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&@James&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++11 language standard has an explanation of how this works at §8.3.2[dcl.ref]/6 (reformatted for readability):

> If a typedef, a type *template-parameter*, or a *decltype-speciﬁer* denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`,
>
> - an attempt to create the type "lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type "lvalue reference to `T`"
> - an attempt to create the type "rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`" creates the type `TR`.

Let's consider your example (I've renamed your `T` to be `TR` so it matches the language above):

```
template<class TR> struct X
{
    static void xxx(TR& x)  { }
    static void xxx(TR&& x) { }
};
```

If we try instantiating `X` with `TR = int&` (so, `T = int`), the instantiations of `xxx` are as follows:

```
static void xxx(TR& x)  { }   -->   static void xxx(int& x) { }
static void xxx(TR&& x) { }   -->   static void xxx(int& x) { }
```

In the first case, we attempt to create an "lvalue reference to `TR`," which becomes an "lvalue reference to `T`."  `T` is `int`, so the parameter type becomes `int&`.

In the second case, we attempt to create an "rvalue reference to `TR`," which becomes `TR`, which is `int&`.

The parameter type is the same for both overloads, hence the error.

Comment: I'm about 70% convinced you've memorized the specs completely

Comment: Thanks for expressing the meaning of TR.

Comment: Is this the rule that makes `std::forward` work? That is, every C++0x programmer will have to know this... :)

Comment: @UncleBens:  This rule wasn't put in for rvalue references, it dates back to before there were rvalue references.  In C++98, "Attempting to create a reference to a reference type" causes type deduction to fail (§14.8.2/2).  [CWG Defect 106](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#106) was raised and its resolution gives us the behavior I describe here (for lvalue references only).  I had thought this rule was included in C++03 (Vandevoorde and Josuttis in _C++ Templates_ expected it to be), but it wasn't.  This rule is required for `forward` to work, though.

Comment: This behavior is called _reference collapsing_ (I just remembered that; it's been driving me nuts all day that I couldn't remember what this was called).